# htaccess rewrite rules causes error while submitting form

Tags: php, forms, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I work around with my htaccess-file for configuring the layout of the urls on my site.

At the moment the problem is that I can not send any forms anymore.

I have two files that exactly will contain the same code (copy & rename). If I call `page1.php` the url will be displayed as `page1.php`. Everything works fine while I will try to login or cause some errors. Now when I will call `index.php` (that has the same code!) the `htaccess` hides `index.php` in the url as it should do! But when I test out the login script, nothing will happen when posting the form. It just refreshes the site. So I have no clue why this is happening?

This behaviour will be defintely caused by the `htaccess` through the rewrite rules. I deleted `htaccess` and tried again. Without it it works but still have this ugly urls.

Okay to show what's in the `htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ %1.php [L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
## rewrite the index file in subdirectories
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

and the form will sent with:

```
form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method= "post"...
```

So if there is someone who could help me out I really would appreciate.

**UPDATE:**

To give further information what I like to achieve:

First of all the structure is the following: because of different languages the root-structure is like:

```
www.domain.com/languagefolder/...
```

Now when an user is calling `www.domain.com` he will be redirected to a `languagesubfolder`. While beeing redirected to the index page of this subfolder the first thing should be that `www.domain.com/languagesfolder/index.php` wont be visible so that it is only `www.domain.com/languagesfolder/`. That will be automatically done. That's fine. But when calling `www.domain.com/languagesfolder/index.php`it should be rewrited as `www.domain.com/languagesfolder/` so that an user can't see `.../index.php`. This seems more professional.

The next thing will be that on further pages links will be given so that an user just needs to enter `.../page` instead of `.../page.php` so that the file extension will not be shown. And last but not least the last thing will be when an user tries to find out what kind of file it is, I would like prevent SQL injection by rewriting the extension so that an user can type `.../page.php` as well as `.../page.html` or `.../page.htm`.

Comment: What is the actual action in the form before you submit it? eg do show source and see what it says?

Comment: Please update your question with some incoming and substitution URL examples. Otherwise it's hard to **guess** what are those rules for and understand what you want to achieve. The rules have a `regex` that is supposed to match a `pattern` in the incoming URL, but that pattern can't be determined without the URL. Your rules don't really help as they don't work.

Comment: Side note: Don't use `PHP_SELF`, [it is vulnerable to XSS attacks](http://seancoates.com/blogs/xss-woes). Instead, to point a form to the current page, use `action=""`

Comment: TL;DR using `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>"` would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method= "post"...
```

To post your form will likely result in something along the lines of:

```
form action = "/index.php" method = "post"...
```

in your code.  The reason you're having a problem with the line:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Is that it's catching the index.php that you're posting to, then redirecting you to http://www.domain.com/ *without* your post data.

If you use firefox and have firebug installed you can see this happening in real-time by viewing the net panel and clicking on persist before submitting your form.  You will see a 301 redirect for POST /index.php follow by a GET for http://www.domain.com/.

You can fix this by replacing the line:

```
form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method= "post"...
```

With:

```
form action = "/" method= "post"...
```

or:

```
form action = "<?php echo rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index.php'); ?>" method= "post"...
```

Which is the same as using str_replace, but will only remove the right-most occurrence of "index.php".

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

From look at the .htaccess and reading through your description it seems a little unclear as to what you are trying to do.  It sounds like you want clean URL's (i.e. never show file extensions), but yet you talk about posting to index.php and such.  If you want to use clean URL's you need to use clean URL's throughout (i.e. post to `/` and not `/index.php`).

You should remove the `AddType` declaration from .htaccess as you should never request a file with .htm or .html extension since all requests would be via clean URL's. You wouldn't need to perform any redirection on `*.index` request other than perhaps as a legacy use case (for external links to your site.

You should be able to simplify your .htaccess to something like this:

```
RewriteEngineOn
# redirect legacy index links. Do this first to clean up URL. No need to use full URL here unless directly to different domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(html|htm|php)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: hello and thanks for helping me. this code causes error 500. the site is unavailable when trying this way. okay and to clarify: yes, i do like to have clean urls. all endings should be deleted. even in case someone tries to enter page.php or page.html he will be redirected to its origin file that can be a php or html file. the next case will be that i do use subfolders for languages and each one has its own index.php - in that case the user should not see index.php at the end of the url, just the path like domain.com/us/ instead of domain.com/us/index.php or even .../us/index

Comment: Hmm what URL request did you make to return the 500?  With regards to your directories and index.php files the first rewrite rule there should take care of all of those. I just simplified down to a single rule. If you can also comment out some lines there to determine the problematic line, that would help, as it is not readily apparent to me.

Comment: hello, i simply called www.domain.com/subfolder/index.php to get this errror. i'm sorry i cant determine any further lines because there are no more in htaccess. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't seem to come from your `.htaccess`. Here is what I tried.

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /stackoverflow/15032042

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ %1.php [L]  

# I don't understand this RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html|php)$ http://www.workspace.domain.tld/stackoverflow/15032042/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.workspace.domain.tld/stackoverflow/15032042/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

index.php:

```
if(isset( $_POST))
    var_dump($_POST);
echo '<form action="" method="POST"><input type="hidden" name="test" value="1" /><input type="submit" /></form>';
```

Then when I hit `http://www.workspace.domain.tld/stackoverflow/15032042/` and submit the form, `$_POST` is shown correctly.

Or maybe you didn't think of your subfolder with `RewriteBase` ?

Comment: hello and thanks for your answer. i found out that this lines: RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(htm|html|php) http://www.domain.com/$1/ [R=301,L]   will cause the error that i got. it seems like that when i will call the /subfolder/index it does not post data maybe because of the rewrite condition that this is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To forward the query string as well you need to add the `QSA` [RewriteRule flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) to the rule or the query string will be discarded. It is also good practice, in most cases and helps keep your sanity, to use the `L` flag which will prevent further rules being processed once a rule was satisfied. You really don't want to mess with multiple rules at the same time, rather make separate `301` rules and deal with the redirects when they return.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Did that solve your problem?

nJoy!

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. i found out that this lines: RewriteRule ^index\.(htm|html|php) domain.com [R=301,L] RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(htm|html|php) domain.com/$1 [R=301,L] will cause the error that i got. it seems like that when i will call the /subfolder/index it does not post data maybe because of the rewrite condition that this is empty.